# How to scale background image based on white space with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2013

I need to scale background image based on the white space left from content div. Here is the sample code:

```
<body class="ms-backgroundImage">
    <div id="s4-workspace">
        <div id="contentRow">
            Custom content here.
        </div>
        (Transparent white space here where the background scales.)
    </div>
</body>
```

For example, if the `#contentRow` height is 60% of the viewport and the white space in `#s4-workspace` is 40%, I need background image that has the height of 40% - 50px of the viewport. And if the `#contentRow` is 90% I'd need background image with the height 10% - 50px (if possible).

Limitations: Because this is a SharePoint system, I'd prefer CSS only modifications rather than HTML (i.e. masterpage). External javascript/jquery is OK if not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are supporting the following browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

You can use the CSS calc() method.

For your specific scenario:

> I need background image that has the height of 40% - 50px of the viewport.

You can use the following CSS:

`selector{height:calc(40vh - 50px);}`

Comment: This solution also uses viewport height units, which [has less browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) than the calc function.

Comment: This is partially working solutions, although it doesn't scale by the height of the div (viewport only) and browser support is limited

Comment: @Pekka, I think you may have the incorrect understanding of what viewport is.  My solution is based off of the viewport size and scales with the viewport.  The viewport is the section of the page that is in view (kind of like screen size).  It has nothing to do with divs or the height of a div.

Comment: Yes, but I need a portion of a div for the height parameter. Unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to do with (current) CSS model.